# Rpi python GPIO PWM Controlling Digital Servo JX 5521MG Problem

Tags: pwm, electronics, servo

I ordered a digital servo [JX 5521MG](http://www.jx-servo.com/English/Product/3015242947.html) to use with my Pi but when I use the code below the servo does not move but there is a slight tick or twitch inside.

```
gpio pwm-ms
gpio pwmc 192
gpio pwmr 2000

gpio -g pwm 18 100
```

I have successfully used the same code with a different model of servo the [FS5103R](http://www.feetechrc.com/product/analog-servo/3kg-cm-360-degree-continuous-rotation-servo-fs5103r/) so I am wondering if I have a faulty servo or whether I need to change the input code.

Comment: Does the same code still work with the other servo?  What frequency and dutycycle do those commands actually produce?

Comment: @joan Yes this still works with the other servo. I also used the following Python Script: pwm=GPIO.PWM(18,300) and pwm.start(32) but the servo just shudders back and forth, not moving the main gear. I have tried with two different power sources (5.0V 2.4A) with the same result. I am thinking the servo could be faulty?

Comment: Could it be that the servo is not able to draw enough current from the supply? The torque is around 20kg/cm3?